# Erro no resultado de um SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select, sql-select

Galera, é o seguinte, estou tendo de fazer um select em um banco, onde eu devo buscar valores que existam entre duas datas, e que tenham um usuário específico. Eu fiz o select assim:

```
SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE `data` BETWEEN 'dataInicio' AND 'dataFim' AND `usuarioID` = 0 OR `adminID` = 2
```

Com isso deveria me aparecer como resultado 2 registros contendo o usuário adminID = 2 no período pesquisado (lancei valores aleatórios para testar). Só que ao invés de aparecer 2 registros, volta todos os registros que o adminID está, sem importar o intervalo de busca da data.
Testei o comando direto no banco MySql, e se eu dividir a query em

```
SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE `data` BETWEEN 'dataInicio' AND 'dataFim'
```

e

```
SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE `usuarioID` = 0 OR `adminID` = 2
```

ambas estão funcionando corretamente, o que pode estar acontecendo quando eu junto ambas?

PS: Agora que eu começei a aprender banco de dados, então se fiz algo muuuuuito burro, desconsidere por favor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você deve isolar a cláusula `OR` da sua `query`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM `tabela`
 WHERE `data` BETWEEN 'dataInicio' AND 'dataFim'
   AND (`usuarioID` = 0 OR `adminID` = 2)
```

Comment: Valeu, realmente não tinha pensado nisso. Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Assim como na matemática precisa dizer qual é a operação que tem maior prioridade, isso é feito atráves de parenteses.

Sua consulta deve ficar assim:

```
SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE
`data` BETWEEN 'dataInicio' AND 'dataFim' AND (`usuarioID` = 0 OR `adminID` = 2)
```

Isso garante que o intervalo da data será respeitado E somente usuários com id zerou ou dois respeitam toda a condição.

Comment: Valeu, realmente não tinha pensado nisso. Obrigado